# read's recursive-p argument when used inside a reader macro

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro

I have written a Common Lisp implementation of Scheme's s-expression comments ([SRFI 62](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-62/srfi-62.html)):

```lisp
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel
            :load-toplevel
            :execute)

  (set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\;
    (lambda (stream char n)
      (declare (ignore char))
      (when n
        (error "Infix parameter not allowed in s-expression comment."))
      (read stream)  ; Discard the s-expression.
      (values))))
```

Based on my reading of [The RECURSIVE-P argument](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/23_acb.htm), it appears that my implementation is incorrect. I have to use `(read stream t nil t)` instead (i.e. set the `recursive-p` argument to `t`). Is my understanding correct?

I have been using the apparently incorrect implementation above, and it seems to function correctly. What would happen if I continue to use `(read stream)` instead of `(read stream t nil t)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example of incorrect behavior, let's consider the first of the three reasons given in the [RECURSIVE-P argument documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/23_acb.htm). First, using your original definition:

```
* (+ 1 #1=2 #;(+ #1# 3))
Reader error: Missing #1# label.
```

Changing `(read stream)` into `(read string t nil t)` gives the correct result:

```
* (+ 1 #1=2 #;(+ #1# 3))
3
```